# how to handle tcp client socket auto reconnect in python asyncio?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio, asyncsocket

I am using python asyncio streams to connect to several socket servers, but when the server is down, my code can't auto reconnect.

What I need is that, when the server is down, my script will try to reconnect every 5 seconds, until connected and start to parse the data again.

```
import asyncio

server1 = {'host': '192.168.1.51', 'port': 11110}
server2 = {'host': '192.168.1.52', 'port': 11110}


async def tcp_client(host, port, loop):
    print('connect to server {} {}'.format(host, str(port)))
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port, loop=loop)

    while True:
        data = await reader.read(100)
        print('raw data received: {}'.format(data))

        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    for server in [server1, server2]:
        loop.run_until_complete(tcp_client(server['host'], server['port'], loop))
        print('task added: connect to server {} {}'.format(server['host'], server['port']))
finally:
    loop.close()
    print('loop closed')
```

Comment: First of all your code will not run: you can't access items in a dictionary using dot notation - use `server['host']` or `server.get('host')`.

Comment: Another problem is that `loop.run_until_complete()` runs until it, well, completes, i.e. it blocks. Thus only one server will be connected at a time.

Comment: And another problem is that `tcp_client()` needs to check if the connection is closed. You can tell that when `data` is the empty string - then return from the function.

Comment: 1. I have corrected the codes. 2. So I need to use loop.call_soon() instead of loop.run_until_complete() to run the task? 3. I can use len(data) == 0 to check if the connection is closed?

Comment: 2. Consider using [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) or [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) 3. See [StreamReader.at_eof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=stream%20api#asyncio.StreamReader.at_eof)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle reconnection by simply looping over a `try/except` statement.

Additionally, [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) can be used to set a timeout on the read operation.

Consider this working example:

```
import asyncio

async def tcp_client(host, port):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
    try:
        while not reader.at_eof():
            data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(100), 3.0)
            print('raw data received: {}'.format(data))
    finally:
        writer.close()

async def tcp_reconnect(host, port):
    server = '{} {}'.format(host, port)
    while True:
        print('Connecting to server {} ...'.format(server))
        try:
            await tcp_client(host, port)
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print('Connection to server {} failed!'.format(server))
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('Connection to server {} timed out!'.format(server))
        else:
            print('Connection to server {} is closed.'.format(server))
        await asyncio.sleep(2.0)

async def main():
    servers = [('localhost', 8888), ('localhost', 9999)]
    coros = [tcp_reconnect(host, port) for host, port in servers]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: I used your code but failed. When I unplug my servers and plugin them again, connection didn't restarted again. below is the log: 2017-05-26 21:39:54,239 - Connecting to server 10.0.1.68 1100 ...
2017-05-26 21:39:54,240 - Connecting to server 10.0.1.69 1100 ...
2017-05-26 21:39:54,977 - raw data received: b'030 1495834968 00.000 00.004 00.010 00.007 00.004 00.000 00.000 00.000\n'

Comment: @DesmondChen Maybe another exception is raised when you unplug your servers, you can try to replace `ConnectionRefusedError` with `Exception`. Also, using `await asyncio.gather(*coros)` will cause your program to stop at the first unexpected exception.

Comment: I changed "ConnectionRefusedError to Exception" and "await asyncio.wait(coros)" to "await asyncio.gather(*coros)". But it still doesn't work. I think that it is stuck at  async def tcp_client(host, port) and no exception raised.

Comment: @DesmondChen You might want to run your tests with netcat servers (e.g. run `nc -l 8888`, write a message to stdin, press enter and interrupt with CTRL+C) to see if the problem comes from your servers.

Comment: It seems that when the buffer is empty, read.at_eof() is still False.

Comment: @DesmondChen If the connection has been closed, `reader.at_eof()` should be True. Do you expect the server or the client to close the connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145222/discussion-between-desmond-chen-and-vincent).